# Find and Replace data in a row and change all rows that have that data in the column

Tags: excel

> I want to change data in row 'I' that has matching text in row 'D'
>   that in their corresponding column.
>
> I have not touched excel since basic programming in sophomore year of
>   high school.
>
> I can elaborate - thank you.

EDIT:

I have data filled in all columns of row 'D'.

These items have a string of text that can be found in Find and Replace tool of Excel.

When Excel Finds the text - I want to do one thing:

Replace all row 'I' data to 'deleted' from 'active'

Comment: As it stands this question is not answerable - you're going to need to add some detail, and describe what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

- Select your data
- Data \ Autofilter (or Alt A T)
- type your string of text in the Search box
- Validate
- Select your I column
- Type `active`, validate with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>